# Trying to prove an experimental result

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

---

I was considering sums of the form

$$ H(x)= \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \left[ 2^{-k}\left(x^{2^k}(1-x^{2^k})\right)^2 \right]$$

Intuitively its the case that $H(x^2 ) = 2H(x)$

Experimentally, I tried graphing these on desmos.com and dividing by $\ln(x)$ and it appears as if they are logarithms. Namely if one graphs

$$\frac{\left[\sum_{n=0}^{40}2^{\left(-n\right)}\left(x^{\left(2^n\right)}\left(1-x^{\left(2^n\right)}\right)\right)^2+\sum_{n=1}^{40}2^{\left(n\right)}\left(x^{\left(2^{-n}\right)}\left(1-x^{\left(2^{-n}\right)}\right)\right)^2\right]}{\ln\left(x\right)} $$

on www.desmos.com yields a graph that looks constant over $x \in (0, 1)$ and equal to -0.4902.

Question is how to prove formally that

$$ H(x)= \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \left[ 2^{-k}\left(x^{2^k}(1-x^{2^k})\right)^2 \right] = c \ln(x) $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closer, it's not constant.  Here's a graph of $H(x)/\ln(x)$ using Maple:

[image]

Computation using $30$ decimal places confirms that $H(0.4)/\log(0.4) \approx -.49022320391$ while $H(0.55)/\log(0.55) \approx 
-.49022691890$.

Comment: Does the graph of the ratio have its "top" of curves equal the same value consistently?

Comment: Since $H(x^2) = 2 H(x)$, yes.

Comment: This appears to be visually similar to $$Q_1 \sin\left( \frac{2\pi}{\ln(2)} \ln \ln (x) + Q_2  \right) + Q_3 $$ for suitable choice of constants $Q_1, Q_2, Q_3$. Would be wild if it actually was though ...